Are the Borrowers just tiny humans or do they have differences, specifically tails or is that another story?
I have the vaguest recollection that they had mouse-like tails. If they did not have tails, was there another book or series about creatures that were like those in The Borrowers that did have tails?

There is a bit of ambiguity in the way you've asked this question: Is it a Story ID question, of "what book am I remembering which is like the Borrowers, but they have tails?" Or is it a story-specific question, of "in the Borrowers, do they have tails or other non-human features?" I have answered one, and Valorum has answered the other, and it's causing some confusion about how to treat the question.

The Borrowers are always depicted simply as scaled down humans. Looking for some images of TV and film adaptations (of which there have been more than I realised) I stumbled on a See Also which I think is what you're remembering:
The Littles, by John Peterson - a long series of books published from 1967 onwards, and a TV cartoon in the early 1970s.
The Wikipedia page about the books isn't very well referenced, but explicitly mentions the similarity to Mary Norton's Borrowers, but with a mouse-like tail. The tails are also clear in many of the cover images on the first book's GoodReads listing.

I've just realised that if this is the answer, the question can be closed as a duplicate of this one: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/121654/childrens-book-series-about-tiny-people?rq=1 (per the site's policy of treating Story ID questions with the same answer as duplicates, regardless of the different angles of the question).

Indeed. I'd missed that they'd marked this one as [tag:story-identification].

I'm not sure if this is really a pure story-ID question though. It sort of combines story-ID (which your answer addresses) with a question about a specific franchise (and the other answer is solely about the Borrowers). It might be wise to not directly dupehammer even if this answer is accepted, or at least to discuss it on meta first.

@Randal'Thor To be honest, I think that's just something that should be clarified by editing the question. My interpretation - which may be wrong - is that the question amounts to "what is this thing I'm remembering, is it some version of the Borrowers or something different?"

I read both when I was young. They are indeed very similar, to the point that I would have answered "yes" to the question by conflating the two.

purely FWIW I'd say this question is quite different, @IMSoP - indeed, this is not at all a story identification question, wouldn't you say?  (It seems to be a question of the form: "In show X [say, Star Trek] did such and such happen [say, 'do they ever time travel']".) I think?

@Fattie As I said to Rand al'Thor, that's really something that needs to be clarified on the Question, not something I have any control over on this Answer.

Are the Littles possibly inspired by Stuart Little?  This predates the series by a few decades, and the titular character definitely has a tail - though not just that, he looks like a mouse all over, albeit a talking intelligent mouse wearing clothes, and his parents are human, no explanation for how that happened, but it's a kid's story...

@IMSoP - right, good one.

The implication from the novel is that the Borrowers are evolved (or possibly devolved) versions of 'little people' like leprechauns or knockers. There's no indication that their physiology is significantly different from our own, other than being much, much smaller. There's no mention of them having tails or any body parts that are abnormal.

"They thought human beings were just invented to do the dirty
work—great slaves put there for them to use. At least, that's what
they told each other. But my brother said that, underneath, he thought
they were frightened. It was because they were frightened, he thought,
that they had grown so small. Each generation had become smaller and
smaller, and more and more hidden. In the olden days, it seems, and in
some parts of England, our ancestors talked quite openly about the
'little people.'"
"Yes," said Kate, "I know."

As you can see from the illustration on the cover of the first edition, the borrowers are noticeably humanoid.

You may have been confused by this book cover for the sequel novel The Borrowers Afield. Arietty's mother is shown with a long red belt/sash that could be mistaken for a tail.

